# custom textbox event not fired

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a custom `TextBox` for border property purposes, but the `OnKeyDown` event is not fired
like original textbox does.

```
public class BorderedTextBox : UserControl
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox;

    public BorderedTextBox()
    {
        textBox = new TextBox()
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Location = new Point(-1, -1),
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom |
                     AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right
        };

        Control container = new ContainerControl()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Padding = new Padding(-1)
        };
        container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(container);


        Padding = new Padding(1);
        Size = textBox.Size;
    }


    public override string Text
    {
        get { return textBox.Text; }
        set { textBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public CharacterCasing CharacterCasing
    {
        get { return textBox.CharacterCasing; }
        set { textBox.CharacterCasing = value; }
    }

    protected override void  OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y,
        int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, textBox.PreferredHeight, specified);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not suppressing the keydown event in Parent Control or Form. ie. `e.SuppressKey = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be fired. Because the focus will be in `TextBox`. `KeyDown` event of textbox will be fired instead.

If you need to handle those events you have few options

- Inherit the `BorderedTextBox` from `TextBox` rather than `UserControl`.
- Subscribe to `textBox.KeyDown` event and handle it.

Comment: It's not working and in addition, border isn't working too :(
I just need a simple bordered TextBox.

Comment: @user1797147 Saying it is not working is not useful. Instead explain what is happening. Also post what you tried now.